Why does splitting a shuffled sequence result in 37%?
Let's say I have a sequence of 1-1000 and I shuffle them. Then I take two numbers at a time and put the lesser into set A and the greater into set B. When I run this experiment many times, and then count how many values in set A have a value less than 501 it seems that set A has a pretty stable value close to 37%.
Why is this? Is 37% the result of the how "shuffled" the original sequence is or can it shown that any random set split like this would converge this way?

Each number has a $\frac{1}{2}$ probability of being greater than $500$. If we take them two at a time, then there is a $\frac{1}{4}$ probability that both numbers are greater than $500$, so a number greater than $500$ will be placed in $A$. Therefore, $\frac{3}{4}$ of the numbers in $A$ are less than $501$ and, since $A$ has half the numbers, we get that $\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{8}=0.375$ of the numbers in $A$ are less than $501$.
